# Post array is missing json from ajax request

Tags: json, codeigniter, jquery

I'm trying to make a dynamic document previewer. The user can input certain document header options and based on their account information it will generate a document with a dynamic header. I eventually want to preview a full pdf but I am working on just the header right now.

What I am trying to do is make a page with a form that the user can fill out, then press a button to preview the header.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
type:       'POST',
timeout:    10000
});

$("#preview_header").click(function(){
    var full_url = //appropriate URL 

    var preview_data = {    
        "wsid":             "default",
        "page":             "default",
        "banner_area1":     "default",
        "banner_area2":     "default",
        "banner_area3":     "default",
        "uid":              "default",
        "fid":              "default",
        "cid":              "default",
        "assignment_type":  "default"
    };

    preview_data.wsid               = $("#worksheet_picker").val();
    preview_data.page               = $("#page_picker").val();
    preview_data.banner_area1       = $("#banner_area1").val();
    preview_data.banner_area2       = $("#banner_area2").val();
    preview_data.banner_area3       = $("#banner_area3").val();
    preview_data.uid                = $("#member_uid").val();
    preview_data.fid                = $("#family_id").val();
    preview_data.assignment_type    = 'family';
    preview_data.cid                = $("#class_id").val();

    var JSONText = JSON.stringify( preview_data );
    alert('Full JSON - ' + JSONText);

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: full_url,
        data: { previewInfo : JSONText }, //Passes necessary form information
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output){
            var reply = output;
            if ( reply.status == "success" ){
                $("#preview").attr("src", reply.image );
            } else {
                alert('Failed to create image preview of the assignment.');
            } 
        } 
    });
});
```

As far as I can tell, the above method is working fine. It hits the right Codeigniter page and when the ajax method is set to return a hard coded image it works just fine. The AJAX seems to be well formatted but just in case here is what it outputs when I fill out forms with the corresponding values:

```
Full JSON - {"wsid":"4","page":"1","banner_area1":"link1",
"banner_area2":"link2","banner_area3":"link3",
"uid":"1","fid":"1","assignment_type":"family"}
```

So first off, let's start with what is working in the corresponding controller method for the ajax reply:

```
$data = array(
'status'    => 'success',
'image'     => //static image link
);

$this->output->set_content_type('text/javascript;charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($data);
```

But whenever I try to modify it like so:

```
$preview_data = json_decode($this->input->post('previewInfo'));

//Got this one
mail('me@gmail.com', 'Start Email', 'Some email' ); 
//Empty email
mail('me@gmail.com', 'Dump Post', var_dump($_POST)); 
//Empty email
mail('me@gmail.com', 'Post data', var_dump($preview_data) );
//returns an email with 1 for body
mail('me@gmail.com', 'Post data', print_r($this->input->post()) ); 
//returns an email with 1 for body
mail('me@gmail.com', 'Post data', 
     print_r($this->input->post('previewInfo')) ); 
//returns an email with 1 for body
mail('me@gmail.com', 'Post data', print_r($preview_data) );

$data = array(
'status'    => 'success',
'image'     => //static image link
);

$this->output->set_content_type('text/javascript;charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($data);
```

The modified one doesn't return the static data either. So it would seem that the post array is not being intialized properly. Anyone see the bug?

Comment: `var_dump` can only output to the browser unless you use output buffering. `print_r` has a second parameter that allows you to return the out as a return value, rather than to the browser. Anyhoo, as a result of this, your return value is not valid JSON, which is likely to prevent your Ajax success callback from working. If you setup the `error` callback too, it should fire as a result. As per @Austin's advise, you should use Firebug or Chrome developer tools to see what is being sent and received.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send your Ajax request with the post method, you need to set `type` to `POST` in your `$.ajax` options.

Also, `async` is true by default, so setting it is not necessary. Additionally, you should consider using `.done` and `.fail` as opposed to `success` and `fail`, as they are slated to be deprecated very soon.

Like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: full_url,
    data: { previewInfo : JSONText }, //Passes necessary form information
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (output, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var reply = output;
    if ( reply.status == "success" ){
        $("#preview").attr("src", reply.image );
    } else {
        alert('Failed to create image preview of the assignment.');
    } 
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // now you have the XHR, text status, and error to debug with
});
```

Comment: I'll try writing it out the way you did but I did do this at the top. Sorry for not including it: $.ajaxSetup({ type:   'POST',timeout: 10000 });.
Thank you for advice. I will change my code accordingly.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that the data from the ajax request is _not_ sent as a json string, but directly to post, so try ditching the json_decode on the server side, see what that does.

Comment: Then check what is happening in your ajax request. Using google chrome, go on to your page that sends the request and hit `f12` to open the console (or `right-click => inspect element`).  Click the `network` tab. Then submit your form that sends the ajax request. You will see the request in the list on the left. Click it. Now look at the details on the right. What is the response? Are you sending the correct values in the request itself?

Answer (score 0):

There was 2 problems that lead to the solution to this problem:

1)

As Austin and Gavin said: var_dump and print_r should not be outputting to the browser.
The solution was to debug with firefox extensions / chrome.

2)

```
$preview_data = json_decode($this->input->post('previewInfo'));
```

was changed to

```
$preview_data = json_decode($this->input->post('previewInfo'), true);
```

The secondy optional parameter of json_decode is to tell the method whether you are expecting an associative object or a list of things. As it happens, I was reading in and wanted an associative array.